# what is the best route to check is username exist?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create a method to check if the username already exists. I have a method to get user details(an object) which have the route as "organization/user/userid" . I want to keep this route for getting details.

So guys could you please tell me, which is the best route for "check if the user exists" method.

Comment: What are the requirements for uniqueness - can usernames exist as duplicates, if they are in different organizations?

Comment: Ideally you would want to create an action attribute and decorate your Register action with that attribute. In that, depending on your **User uniqueness** business rules, you will detect if the user exists and whether your action should run or return

Answer (score 0):

For grabbing user details it could look like this :-

```
organization/user/details/{userid}
```

For checking if a user exists:-

```
organization/user/{userid}
```